# Sql Sync Framework 2.0

Tags: sql-server, synchronization

I have working on sql sync framework as a university project, i am getting following error Invalid object name 'scope_info'. I am attaching a screen shot to show the issue, kindly please help. If any thing else required please comment.[image]

Platform: Windows xp
Visual studio 2010
Sql Server 2008 / Express 2008
Sql Sync Framework 2.0

Answer (score 1):

When you provision using sync framework it creates some metadata table those tables are schema_info, scope_config, scope_info, In addition to that it will create corresponding tracking table for all the tables in syn scope.

Make sure you have schema_info table and all tracking tables. If not deprvision sync scope and reprovision and try again. 
See the detail documentation of how provision and deprovison

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928603.aspx